# React Native state with arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, react-native, state

I'm using arrays with state but I'm not sure why I can get but not set using the array. I have:

```
      getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      stored: {'ok':1,'maybe':1,'then':1}
    };
  },
```

I can get the array item no problem like this:

```
        <Text style={styles.text}>
           {this.state.stored['ok']==1 ? "yes" : ""}
        </Text>
```

But strangely trying to set state doesn't allow to refer to the array item and throws an error:

```
  this.setState({stored['ok']: 1});
```

Comment: Still looking for an answer here - anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will works if you will replace entire hash with new one.

Try something like this:

```
var newHash = this.state.stored;
newHash['ok'] = 1;
this.setState({ stored: newHash });
```

But it will be better not to store hashes in state.

Comment: Yeah that does work, thanks. Why doesn't it work the way I did it though? Seems weird to have to do it this way.

Comment: A object's key wouldn't be an array

Comment: But it works as an array when initialising it and also when retrieving it. The only time it doesn't is when setting it.

Comment: Hmm did you realise what you wrote actually doesn't do anything at all. The objective was to update the value of this.state.stored['ok'] but instead you're just assigning the current value of this.state.stored to newhash and then reassigning it to stored. It doesn't actually change anything. Attempting to access the array after assignment just returns undefined.

Comment: Basically you're just assigning the value of 1 to stored and not stored['ok']. The same code you've written can be written like this in a single line: this.setState({ stored: this.state.stored['ok]}); but it obviously doesn't work either.